# Signtool: "The specified PFX password is not correct" on Windows Server 2012

Tags: certificate, sign, signing, pfx, signtool

I'm trying to sign my file with the following command:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64\signtool.exe sign /f "PATH_TO_PFX_FILE" /p PASSWORD "PATH_TO_FILE"
```

On Windows Server 2012 machine, the command fails with the message:

```
SignTool Error: The specified PFX password is not correct.
```

However, the same command in Windows 10 works successfully and both machines use the same version of signtool.

Why it doesn't work on only Windows Server 2012?